# Create temporary or virtual File in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am using a database to store a blob. I am then using JPA to read the blob into an entity. So basically I have a `byte[]`.

There is a class in a library that I am using whose constructor takes either a `foo(String filePath)` or `foo(File file)`.

I am using EJBs so I do not have access to the servers file system. All I have is the binary data for the blob. Is there a way I can create a File object in some fashion that points to my data in the EJB world so that I can use my library? Some kind or wrapper?

Comment: That's really a poorly designed API. Create an enhancement request at their issue tracker wherein you request them to add a method taking a normal `InputStream`.

Comment: You best option (given the circustances) is to flush your binary array to a temporal file (i.e. `File.createTempFile(...)`) using `FileOutputStream`, call the library, and later delete your temporal file ...

Answer (score 1):

Although you should not create files within the EJB environment, much less have a folder associated with your application through the File class of Java SE can create a temporary file which will be stored on the temporary files folder of the user It has associated the application server process. For example, the following code fragment create a temporary file that will be placed in the temporary files folder

```
File tempV1 = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");
//C:\Users\JAVIER~1.ZAM\AppData\Local\Temp\file4872171473798955694.tmp
```

If you assign a special folder for temporary files, you can pass it as a parameter as follows:

```
File tempV2 = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp",  
                                   new File("c:/server/temporal"));
//C:\server\temporal\file631043069173548312.tmp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might be useful to add some explanation to your code as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(byteArray);
fos.close();
```

The real file will not be created till you invoke method createNewFile() on your file object.

Comment: Will I be able to access the byte[] data without creating the file?

Comment: Regardings your question, you want to have a File object that point to your data. If you don't need the File object, you can just convert it to ByteArrayInputStream and do whatever you want on this stream.

Comment: *"The real file will not be created till you invoke method createNewFile() on your file object."* Sorry, this is nonsense.

Comment: Can you explain more about this, please? @BalusC